# startActivity does not create activity the second time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two applications installed on my device, application A and application B.

When a user launches application A, they press a button to launch application B.

I use the following code:

```
Intent intent = Global.CurrentContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("some.random.app");
Global.CurrentContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The first time the user does this, it works fine and works as expected, however, if the user then launches the phones task manager and swipes away application B. When the user then presses the button in application A. The activity is not created.

I believe this is something to do with the way that the task and the activity are being destroyed by android. My thought process is that when the user swipes to kill application B that the activity is destroyed, but the task remains. Then the second time they press the button in application A, that it's attaching to the old task and then not showing for the user.

Application A's activity manifest for the activity:

```
<activity
            android:name="a.a.a.LogonActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Application B's activity manifest for the activity:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: try adding flags  `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);`

Comment: I have added those flags and the result is no different sadly! Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

When I set `android:noHistory="false"`, it works. I think it is `android:noHistory="true"` killed applicationA's top activity, makes it doesn't work.

Comment: I have ammended the noHistory and the same problem remains sadly! Thanks though